# Is a carbon fibre cyclocross or mountain bike likely to be lighter than an aluminum roadbike?

Tags: carbon

If the two are the same frame size, generally roadbikes are lighter. But if the roadbike is aluminum and the mountain bike is carbonfibre, is it probable the mountain bike frame will weigh less?

Comment: How much does the frame weigh?  How much do you weigh?  How much does it matter?

Comment: What is the purpose of comparing the frame weight of three different styles of bikes?  Cyclocross is more like a road than a mountain.   How would you compare a road size to mountain size?

Comment: "Is this apple lighter than this hammer?"   I don't think this question can be answered because the two bikes are for different purposes.  The MTB's tyres are going to weigh three or more times more than the road bike's tyres.  Compare just the bare frames might give you a better answer, but what are you actually trying to find out?   If you're exclusively riding road, buy a road bike.  If you're going a lot on grass and gravel, buy a CX, and if you're going on a track where you need to slow down to prevent bike damage, buy a MTB.   Then you can start comparing features/numbers.

Comment: You're trying to compare apples to oranges. You wouldn't compare running shoes to hiking boots because they serve different purposes. What's the point of making such a useless comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible, maybe even likely. If you reword the question to "Is an aluminum framed road bike always heavier than a carbon cyclocross or MTB?" the answer is definitely no.

Manufacturers play games with frame materials and fool people into thinking because the have a carbon frame they have the lightest. They also play games fooling people into thinking lighter is better.

The frame makes up about .8kg-2kg of a road bike and 1.2-2kg of a MTB. The difference between light road frames and MTB frames is less than the variation on the frames of each class.

But the fame makes up only 10% of the weight of a bike.....

Comment: Thank you for taking an imperfect question seriously, and providing a constructive answer which gave me some things to think about.